# Do giant gouramis tolerate tank mates?

Tags: fish, aquarium, gourami, community-aquarium

Right now, I have 2 fish tanks in my home and it is very difficult for me to maintain both at the same time.  I have attached images of both fish tanks and fish living in them.

In the first fish tank I have a single giant gourami.

**First tank picture:**

[image]

In the second fish tank I have:

1. Kissing gourami
2. Milky white koi carp
3. Sliver shark
4. Blue gourami
5. Twin fin
6. Sea angel
7. *Hypostomus plecostomus*

**Second tank picture:**

[image]

I have heard that giant gourami can kill the other fish like oscar and arowana.

My question is, can the giant gourami live with all these fish in a single tank, or do I have to keep it alone?

If I put them in a single tank, what kind of filtration is required?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking if you can put all these fish together in one of these two tanks? How large are the tanks, and what kind of filtration you have on them? To be honest, just from the pictures both of them look overstocked already. Also, the question about the gourami's gender would be better as a separate question.

Comment: @toxotes: Yes you're right, My Questions can i place all the fishes in a single tank becasue i heard giant gourami can i kill the other fish like oscar and arowana fish ? or shall i keep them in different tanks and also if put them in a single tank , what kind of filtration is required?

Comment: What size are these tanks?

Comment: @SankarGanesh the general rule of thumb is that most fish will eat any other fish that they can fit in their mouth, given the opportunity.  From the looks of the photos, I would not put those fish into a single tank and expect all of them to survive - not at least until they reach full adult size.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: can you please post your comments as answer, i have to accept your comments and answer, because i tried to put plecostomus in that tank1, as you said the general rule of thumb , giant gourami proves that rule of thumb is correct. it tried to chase the plecostomus , then i removed plecostomus from that tank. previously what i thought is that giant gourami can live with some other type of fishes , but now i have understood the rule of thumb, Thanks very much mate

Answer (score 12):

Going by your pictures, no, you can't combine these fish. Please don't take this the wrong way: these tanks are much too small for the animals in them, and have inadequate filtration. Giant gouramis get huge, bigger than some cats and dogs -- you're looking at a fish that needs several hundred gallons of water.

The other tank already has too many huge, incompatible fish, so the behavior of the giant gourami is not really relevant. I think your silver shark is what I know as a Bala shark, which will grow to be over a foot long. I've  seen plecos easily reach two feet in length. The koi will reach, at minimum, a foot long.

I know this is not the answer you're asking for, but I really don't think your fish are going to do well like this.  People say fish only grow to the size of their tank, but what actually happens is they just don't survive long enough to reach their full size in those conditions. The fact that you're already having trouble keeping up with maintenance is a warning sign.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so giant gourami can live with these fish , no problem for living with them, can you please convey the tank size and filteration , so that i can buy a single tank with the size you have mentioned and place them all in one tank .

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me: I'm not saying they could live together in a bigger tank. I'm saying it doesn't matter if they could because *these* tanks look much too small. From what I know about gouramis, I suspect you can't put them together even if you had the space.

Comment: ok Thank you so much toxotes , now i have a dobut , I m planning to buy a new tank for giant gourami, can you please specify size of tank is required for the giant gourami , and also is it possible to put any of the other fishes from Tank 1 in that new tank ( which i am going to purchase for giant gourami ) along with giant gourami.

Comment: @SankarGanesh you will need 100 gallon tank for your giant gourmanis. And yes after you have such an enormous tank, and it is well planted, has a sump and proper substrate and filtration, then you can keep all these fish together. But from what your pictures suggest, I would recommend to read up on basics of freshwater fish keeping before proceeding, or you will waste a lot of money and kill lots of fish.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend keeping the giant gourami with any of the fish you have in your second tank. Many of your other fish will likely get eaten by the gourami. Also, some of the fish currently housed together in the second tank are not actually compatible long-term.

Koi should not be kept at tropical temperatures. Keeping them at temperatures warm enough for all the other fish in that tank speeds up their metabolism, strains their system, and dramatically decreases their life expectancy.

Your silver sharks will likely get large enough to be a threat to many of the other fish in that tank.

Your pleco may eventually start trying to eat the slime coat off of other fish in the tank. This will leave them prone to infection and disease.

The giant gourami may eventually exceed two feet in length and need a huge tank even if it is kept alone. Any other fish in the tank would have to be large enough not to be eaten and either robust/armoured enough or agile enough not to be injured by the gourami. And adding more large fish may mean increasing the required tank dimensions even more! For a large full-grown specimen, you'll already be looking at a tank with dimensions of approximately 6' x 2' x 2' (183 x 61 x 61 cm) - around 180 US gallons (680 liters)!

You may be able to get away with a more modestly sized tank (of 100 or 125 gallons / 380 to 470 liters) *if* your particular gourami only grows to the 18" (46 cm) that seems to be more typical for captive specimens, but there's no guarantee that will be the case.

The pleco (if it's a "common" pleco) also has the potential to reach 18-24" (46-61 cm) in length. As does the koi. The sharks will likely be in the range of 12-14" (30-36 cm) when full-grown.

You'd actually be best off having three or four separate tanks for all the fish you have listed. If that is not practical for you at this time, it might be best to look into re-homing some of the fish. There may be another fish enthusiast in your area who would be thrilled to adopt some of yours or there may be a pet store that would be willing to take them on.

Answer (score -2):

You can have giant gourami with any fish like oscar, koi carp, angel, giant gouramis, etc. but you have to keep the fish together from the beginning - in other words, no later than when giant gourami is as small as 1 to 2 inches (2.5 to 5.0 cm) in length.

I have three, one and a half foot giant gourami with 10 oscars and koi carp in a 5 foot (150 cm) long tank.

The only problem ism if you add new fish (giant gourami) then immediately it will be killed by the other fish.

Comment: Actually, koi are not tropical fish and need significantly cooler water than most of the other fish listed.

Answer (score -4):

you can keep them with each other but in one condition your tank is too small you have to need 
a 20-30 gallon tank with hidings and rocks fore fishes which thought nessary to hide 
fist you should observe fishes that they are not fighting  if they are not so you can keep
them which each other 
secondly in big tank filteration you can consult aqarium shopkeeper  or other wise you could 
place a high power aquarium filter.  :)

Comment: If the fish live through it, they'll outgrow a 30 gallon tank. Just the bala sharks and pleco will get to be around a foot long when full grown. Though the Giant Gourami will probably just eat them before they grow if kept together.